# how to increase the omniture s.prop variable 100-character maximum limit?

Tags: adobe-analytics

Adobe analytics omniture, s.prop variables have a 100-character maximum limit. so how to increase this limit to see full URL in site-catalyst report?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you don't need the full URL, you might want to think about processing it in javascript to remove the protocol and domain, leaving just the path and file.  That might give you another 20+ characters.

Answer (score 3):

Max 100 byte for `props` is a limit enforced on Adobe's processing server. If you send a value in that's longer, Adobe will truncate it on their server while processing.  Adobe does not currently offer any options for lengthening it.

Depending on what your tracking/report needs are, you can track it as an `eVar` instead, which has a 255 byte limit.

Also note that I said "byte" not "character", which isn't necessarily the same length, depending on the character. For example, you can send data in some other language e.g. mandarin that's multi-byte, whose characters may take multiple bytes.  IOW some characters can be more than one byte in size, and the limit is bytes, not characters.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Crayon, you can grab the value in eVar and then have your processing rule work on that eVar. Mostly this causes an issue with page name